# Suppose $P (1) + P (2) = 3P (3)$ and $P (2) + P (3) = P (1)$ for a sample space $(S,P)$ . Find the probability function.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

So we have the following equations:

$P(1) + P(2) = 3P(3)$
$P(2) + P(3) = P(1)$

I know that by definition, $P(1) + P(2) + P(3) = 1$

I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for as my answer though. Are there any other equations hiding that could be useful here? Hints are fine.

I've worked out that I can end up with $4P(3) = 1$ by using those three equations.

Comment: Hint: Substitute one of the two equations into the third.

Comment: It's just asking you to find the three numbers $P(1),P(2),P(3).$

Comment: Ah, okay! So far I have found that P(3) = 1/4. I will post an answer when I find the others.

Comment: The function $P()$ is called a *probability mass function*. There is also the *cumulative probability (distribution) function*, which you can find once you have $P()$. (The question is ambiguous if it only says "probability function".)

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please let me know if anything can be improved. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve this problem.

Since we know that $P(1) + P(2) + P(3) = 1$ by definition, we have the following three equations:

$P(1) + P(2) = 3P(3)$
$P(2) + P(3) = P(1)$
$P(1) + P(2) + P(3) = 1$

Plugging the first equation into the third, we get $4P(3) = 1$. So $P(3) = \frac{1}{4}$.

From the last equation, we get $P(2) = 1 - P(3) - P(1) \Rightarrow P(2) = \frac{3}{4} - P(1)$.

Now substitute that into the second equation to find that $P(1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Lastly, we can return to the first equation to find that $P(2) = \frac{1}{4}$.

So we have:
$P(1) = \frac{1}{2}$
$P(2) = \frac{1}{4}$
$P(3) = \frac{1}{4}$

More formally, for all $x \in S = \{1, 2, 3\}$,

$$P(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2},  & \text{$x$ = 1} \\[2ex]
\frac{1}{4}, & \text{$x \in \{2, 3\}$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: You might want to say "for all $x\in S=\{1,2,3\}$", to make the sample space explicit. Also, "$x\in\{2,3\}$" might be better than "(else)"